# How to apply the same JQuery to two navs and add a different class for each nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented this [Vertical Fixed Navigation](https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-fixed-navigation/) from [Codyhouse](http://codyhouse.co) into my site and everything works fine. The problem is with the fixed main-nav I have on top of the page (i.e. two navs in total, one on top and one vertical).

I would like to make both navigations behave the same, i.e. smooth scrolling and toggling class depending on scroll position, with a specific addClass for each nav. 
I tried to select the links elements from both navs this way:

```
var navigationItems = $('#cd-vertical-nav a', '#main-nav a')
```

but it didn't work. As a matter of fact, in the snippet below the JQuery isn't working too. Dunno why :) But in my site the vertical nav works fine.

I am still a noob coder and new at StackOverflow. I would really appreciate any help!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var contentSections = $('.cd-section'),
    navigationItems = $('#cd-vertical-nav a');

  updateNavigation();
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    updateNavigation();
  });

  //smooth scroll to the section
  navigationItems.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll($(this.hash));
  });
  //smooth scroll to second section
  $('.arrow-down').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll($(this.hash));
  });

  //open-close navigation on touch devices
  $('.touch .cd-nav-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav').toggleClass('open');

  });
  //close navigation on touch devices when selectin an elemnt from the list
  $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav a').on('click', function() {
    $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav').removeClass('open');
  });

  function updateNavigation() {
    contentSections.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      var activeSection = $('#cd-vertical-nav a[href="#' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').data('number') - 1;
      if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height() / 2 > $(window).scrollTop())) {
        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('is-selected');
      } else {
        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('is-selected');
      }
    });
  }

  function smoothScroll(target) {
    $('body,html').animate({
        'scrollTop': target.offset().top - 120
      },
      1500, 'easeOutExpo'
    );
  }
});
```

```css
.main-header-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
header {
  background: DarkGray;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu,
.menu__list {
  padding: 0;
}
.menu__list {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.menu__link {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.75em 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
.menu__link:hover,
.menu__link:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: yellow;
}
.menu__item--current .menu__link {
  color: yellow;
}
.menu__link::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.1s;
}
.menu__item--current .menu__link::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
/****Vertical Nav Styles****/

#cd-vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
#cd-vertical-nav li {
  text-align: right;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a span {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-dot {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
.cd-section {
  height: 400px;
}
#landing-section {
  background: DarkCyan;
}
#biography-section {
  background: CornflowerBlue;
}
#recordings-section {
  background: OrangeRed;
}
#gallery-section {
  background: Coral;
}
#contact-section {
  background: MediumPurple;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="main-header-container">
  <header>

    <nav class="menu clearfix" id="main-nav">
      <ul class="menu__list">

        <li class="menu__item menu__item--current" id="news">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#landing-section" data-number="1">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="biography">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#biography-section" data-number="2">Biography</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="recordings">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#recordings-section" data-number="3">Recordings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="gallery">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#gallery-section" data-number="4">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="contact">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#contact-section" data-number="5">Contact</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="vertical-nav1">
      <a href="#landing-section" data-number="1">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">News</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav2">
      <a href="#biography-section" data-number="2">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Biography</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav3">
      <a href="#recordings-section" data-number="3">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Recordings</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav4">
      <a href="#gallery-section" data-number="4">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Gallery</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav5">
      <a href="#contact-section" data-number="5">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Contact</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="landing-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="biography-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="recordings-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="gallery-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="contact-section" class="cd-section"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple elements, you put them in a single selector string, separated by commas, not separate arguments to the `jQuery()` function.

```
var navigationItems = $('#cd-vertical-nav a, #main-nav a');
```

When you call `jQuery` with multiple arguments, the first argument is a selector, and the second argument is the context to search within, i.e.

```
$('#cd-vertical-nav a', '#main-nav a')
```

is equivalent to

```
$('#main-nav a').find('#cd-vertical-nav a')
```

Another way you can do this in a more general way is to use a class.

```
<nav class="menu clearfix fixed-nav" id="main-nav">
<nav class="fixed-nav" id="cd-vertical-nav">
```

Then you can use `$('.fixed-nav a')`.

Comment: The `$('.fixed-nav a')` did the job! Thank you!

Comment: I am now trying to add a specific class to the active link based on scroll position. I try my best and then will probably beg again for help! :) But of course I am here to learn and will try first myself. Thanks a lot already for the first help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [mutliplse selector syntax](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
navigationItems = $('#cd-vertical-nav a, #main-nav a')
```

If you pass the second selector as a separate argument, then it will be considered as a [context parameter](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var contentSections = $('.cd-section'),
    navigationItems = $('#cd-vertical-nav a, #main-nav a');

  updateNavigation();
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    updateNavigation();
  });

  //smooth scroll to the section
  navigationItems.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll($(this.hash));
  });
  //smooth scroll to second section
  $('.arrow-down').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll($(this.hash));
  });

  //open-close navigation on touch devices
  $('.touch .cd-nav-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav').toggleClass('open');

  });
  //close navigation on touch devices when selectin an elemnt from the list
  $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav a').on('click', function() {
    $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav').removeClass('open');
  });

  function updateNavigation() {
    contentSections.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      var activeSection = $('#cd-vertical-nav a[href="#' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').data('number') - 1;
      if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height() / 2 > $(window).scrollTop())) {
        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('is-selected');
      } else {
        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('is-selected');
      }
    });
  }

  function smoothScroll(target) {
    console.log('x', target.get())
    $('body,html').animate({
        'scrollTop': target.offset().top - 120
      },
      1500, 'easeOutExpo'
    );
  }
});
```

```css
.main-header-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
header {
  background: DarkGray;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu,
.menu__list {
  padding: 0;
}
.menu__list {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.menu__link {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.75em 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
.menu__link:hover,
.menu__link:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: yellow;
}
.menu__item--current .menu__link {
  color: yellow;
}
.menu__link::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.1s;
}
.menu__item--current .menu__link::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
/****Vertical Nav Styles****/

#cd-vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
#cd-vertical-nav li {
  text-align: right;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a span {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-dot {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
.cd-section {
  height: 400px;
}
#landing-section {
  background: DarkCyan;
}
#biography-section {
  background: CornflowerBlue;
}
#recordings-section {
  background: OrangeRed;
}
#gallery-section {
  background: Coral;
}
#contact-section {
  background: MediumPurple;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="main-header-container">
  <header>

    <nav class="menu clearfix" id="main-nav">
      <ul class="menu__list">

        <li class="menu__item menu__item--current" id="news">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#landing-section" data-number="1">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="biography">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#biography-section" data-number="2">Biography</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="recordings">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#recordings-section" data-number="3">Recordings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="gallery">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#gallery-section" data-number="4">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="contact">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#contact-section" data-number="5">Contact</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="vertical-nav1">
      <a href="#landing-section" data-number="1">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">News</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav2">
      <a href="#biography-section" data-number="2">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Biography</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav3">
      <a href="#recordings-section" data-number="3">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Recordings</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav4">
      <a href="#gallery-section" data-number="4">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Gallery</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav5">
      <a href="#contact-section" data-number="5">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Contact</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="landing-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="biography-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="recordings-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="gallery-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="contact-section" class="cd-section"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    var navigationItems = $('#cd-vertical-nav>a', '#main-nav>a');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the jQuery (see the updated snippet) in order to add a class to the active link of each nav, based on scroll position.
There must be a problem here (also somewhere else?):

```
updateMainNavigation()
updateVerticalNavigation()
```

Here they are comma separated but I also tried to write two complete different functions, even if the behaviour is the same. I can't figure out what I should do to make it work.
I am the same noob as yesterday and any help ist most welcome!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var contentSections = $('.cd-section'),
    navigationItems = $('.fixed-nav a');

  updateMainNavigation(), updateVerticalNavigation();
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    updateMainNavigation(), updateVerticalNavigation();
  });

  //smooth scroll to the section
  navigationItems.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll($(this.hash));
  });
  //smooth scroll to second section
  $('.arrow-down').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll($(this.hash));
  });

  function updateMainNavigation() {
    contentSections.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      var activeSection = $('#main-nav a[href="#' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').data('number') - 1;
      if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height() / 2 > $(window).scrollTop())) {
        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('menu__item--current');
      } else {
        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('menu__item--current');
      }
    });
  }

  function updateVerticalNavigation() {
    contentSections.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      var activeSection = $('#cd-vertical-nav a[href="#' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').data('number') - 1;
      if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height() / 2 > $(window).scrollTop())) {
        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('is-selected');
      } else {
        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('is-selected');
      }
    });
  }

  function smoothScroll(target) {
    $('body,html').animate({
        'scrollTop': target.offset().top - 120
      },
      1500, 'easeOutExpo'
    );
  }
});
```

```css
.main-header-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
header {
  background: DarkGray;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu,
.menu__list {
  padding: 0;
}
.menu__list {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.menu__link {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.75em 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
.menu__link:hover,
.menu__link:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: yellow;
}
.menu__item--current .menu__link {
  color: yellow;
}
.menu__link::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.1s;
}
.menu__item--current .menu__link::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
/****Vertical Nav Styles****/

#cd-vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
#cd-vertical-nav li {
  text-align: right;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a span {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-dot {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
.cd-section {
  height: 400px;
}
#landing-section {
  background: DarkCyan;
}
#biography-section {
  background: CornflowerBlue;
}
#recordings-section {
  background: OrangeRed;
}
#gallery-section {
  background: Coral;
}
#contact-section {
  background: MediumPurple;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="main-header-container">
  <header>

    <nav class="menu clearfix" id="main-nav">
      <ul class="menu__list">

        <li class="menu__item menu__item--current" id="news">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#landing-section" data-number="1">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="biography">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#biography-section" data-number="2">Biography</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="recordings">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#recordings-section" data-number="3">Recordings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="gallery">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#gallery-section" data-number="4">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item" id="contact">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#contact-section" data-number="5">Contact</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="vertical-nav1">
      <a href="#landing-section" data-number="1">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">News</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav2">
      <a href="#biography-section" data-number="2">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Biography</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav3">
      <a href="#recordings-section" data-number="3">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Recordings</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav4">
      <a href="#gallery-section" data-number="4">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Gallery</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="vertical-nav5">
      <a href="#contact-section" data-number="5">
        <span class="cd-dot"></span>
        <span class="cd-label">Contact</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="landing-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="biography-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="recordings-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="gallery-section" class="cd-section"></section>
<section id="contact-section" class="cd-section"></section>
```