# How to apply same jQuery to two different nav menus

Tags: jquery

On a dev site I'm having a fixed vertical navigation taken from a  [Codyhouse tutorial](https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-fixed-navigation/) and a second nav that's fixed (horizontal) to the top of the page.

I'd like the code below to apply the ".active" selector to both menu items when clicked. At this moment I can only get it to work on one or the other and not both at the same time (so if I comment out one menu then the other menu will apply the `.active` selector).

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        var contentSections = $('.slide'),
            navigationItems = $('.nav a');

        updateNavigation();
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            updateNavigation();
        });

        //smooth scroll to the section
        navigationItems.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            smoothScroll($(this.hash));
        });
        //scroll top
        $('.scrollToTop').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            smoothScroll($(this.hash));
        });


        function updateNavigation() {
            contentSections.each(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                var activeSection = $('.nav a[href="#' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').data('number') - 1;
                if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height() / 2 > $(window).scrollTop())) {
                    navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('active'); // for the main menu
                } else {
                    navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('active');
                }
            });
        }
        // sets scroll for mobi height
        function smoothScroll(target, time) {
            var margin = ($('.primary-nav').outerHeight(true));
            if (!time) {
                time = '1500';
            }

            //sets scroll for desktop height
            if ($(window).width() > 785) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': target.offset().top
                }, time);
            } else {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - margin
                }, time);
            }
        }

    });
```

HTML

```
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="primary-nav">
                    <li><a href="#slide01" data-number="1">Intro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide02" data-number="2">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide03" data-number="3">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide04" data-number="4">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide05" data-number="5">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide06" data-number="6">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>


            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="dot-nav">
                    <li class="dot-charm" title="Intro"><a href="#slide01" data-number="1"><span class="nav-dot"></span><span class="nav-label">Intro</span></a></li>
                    <li class="dot-charm" title="Portfolio"><a href="#slide02" data-number="2"><span class="nav-dot"></span><span class="nav-label">Portfolio</span></a></li>
                    <li class="dot-charm" title="About"><a href="#slide03" data-number="3"><span class="nav-dot"></span><span class="nav-label">About</span></a></li>
                    <li class="dot-charm" title="Services"><a href="#slide04" data-number="4"><span class="nav-dot"></span><span class="nav-label">Services</span></a></li>
                    <li class="dot-charm" title="News"><a href="#slide05" data-number="5"><span class="nav-dot"></span><span class="nav-label">News</span></a></li>
                    <li class="dot-charm" title="Contact"><a href="#slide06" data-number="6"><span class="nav-dot"></span><span class="nav-label">Contact</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

  <section id="slide01" class="slide"></section>
  <section id="slide02" class="slide"></section>
  <section id="slide03" class="slide"></section>
  <section id="slide04" class="slide"></section>
  <section id="slide05" class="slide"></section>
  <section id="slide06" class="slide"></section>
```

CSS

```
    /*Horizontal Nav*/

    .primary-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        bottom: auto;
        transform: translateY(-200%);
        transition: transform .3s;
        right: 0;
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 30px 20px;
        background: #FECD04
    }

    .primary-nav.is-visible {
        transform: translateY(0);
        transition: transform .3s
    }

    .primary-nav li {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 0
    }

    .primary-nav a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #383838;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 17px 0;
        width: 100%
    }

    .primary-nav a:hover {
        color: grey
    }


    /*Vert Nav*/

    #nav-dots {
        position: fixed;
        right: 50px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        text-align: right;
        z-index: 100
    }

    #nav-dots a {
        display: block;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 20px;
        color: #FECD04;
        text-decoration: none
    }

    #nav-dots a:hover .nav-label {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible
    }

    #nav-dots nav {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1
    }

    #nav-dots .dot-charm {
        background: transparent;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-left: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-right: 12px solid #FECD04;
        height: 8%;
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 20px;
        opacity: .1;
        width: 14px
    }

    #nav-dots .nav-label {
        display: block;
        opacity: .5;
        visibility: hidden;
        transform: translateX(-10px);
        transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.83, 0.67)
    }


    /*Sections*/

    .slide {
        padding: 80px 15px;
        position: relative
    }
```

I have noted that this question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642861/how-to-apply-the-same-jquery-to-two-navs-and-add-a-different-class-for-each-nav) but I tried everything that was suggested there and got nowhere.

Any help with this would be great thanks.

Comment: can you add some of the css, in order we can test your code?

Comment: You define `contentSections = $('.slide');` but I don't see anything with that class, so I don't see how `contentSections.each()` runs at all.

Comment: doh, added now.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the following and it worked for me.

```
    $(document).ready(function($) {
            var contentSections = $('.slide'),
                navigationItems = $('.nav a');
                dotNavigationItems  = $('.dot-nav a');

            updateNavigation();
            updateSecondNavigatioin();
            $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                updateNavigation();
                updateSecondNavigatioin();
            });

            //smooth scroll to the section
            navigationItems.on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                smoothScroll($(this.hash));
            });
            //scroll top
            $('.scrollToTop').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                smoothScroll($(this.hash));
            });


            function updateNavigation() {
                contentSections.each(function() {
                    $this = $(this);
                    var activeSection = $('.nav a[href="#' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').data('number') - 1;
                    if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height() / 2 > $(window).scrollTop())) {
                        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('active'); // for the main menu
                    } else {
                        navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }


            function updateSecondNavigatioin() {
                contentSections.each(function() {
                    $this = $(this);
                    var activeSection = $('.dot-nav a[href="#' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').data('number') - 1;
                    if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height() / 2 > $(window).scrollTop())) {
                        dotNavigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('selected'); // for the second menu
                    } else {
                        dotNavigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('selected');
                    }
                });
            }


            // sets scroll for mobi height
            function smoothScroll(target, time) {
                var margin = ($('.primary-nav').outerHeight(true));
                if (!time) {
                    time = '1500';
                }

                //sets scroll for desktop height
                if ($(window).width() > 785) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        'scrollTop': target.offset().top
                    }, time);
                } else {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top - margin
                    }, time);
                }
            }

        });
```